# jQuery on click repeat twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a box to appear when the user clicks onto a button.
Once the button is clicked a box appears with an animation.
The box has a close button within.
One the close button is pressed, and the open button is pressed again the animation does not repeat.

Why would this be?

I have a link to a JS fiddle file below:

https://jsfiddle.net/harryB/va2r1pkm/

Here is the jQuery.

```
$('body').on('click', '.modal-button', function () {

// show box and bg on click of button

var el = $('#modal-bg').fadeIn();

$('.modal-box').animate({

    top: "+=300"
}, 1000, function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

});


});
$('.modal-box .fa').on('click', function () {
    // show box and bg on click of button
    $('#modal-bg').fadeOut();

});
```

Comment: Because top is still 300px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you looking for:

Made couple of changes, like `margins`, and `top` positions.

**<kbd>[Working : DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/va2r1pkm/3/)</kbd>**

**Snippet**

```js
// create a modal that appears once button is pressed.
// modal has a close button within.
// background is covered modal so modal stands out.

$('body').on('click', '.modal-button', function () {

    // show box and bg on click of button
    
    var el = $('#modal-bg').fadeIn();
  
    $('.modal-box').animate({

        top: "200px" // Chnaged top position value. You can define whatever you want.
    }, 1000);
      
});
$('.modal-box .fa').on('click', function () {
    // show box and bg on click of button
    $('.modal-box').animate({"top":"-100vh"},800);
    $('#modal-bg').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
#modal-bg {
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    background:rgba(234, 234, 234, 0.66);
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
}
.modal-box {
    padding:20px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0px auto 50px auto; /* Changed Top Margin to 0 */
    background:green;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    /* Removed Top Margin */
}
.modal-box .fa {
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="modal-button">Read More</button>
<div id="modal-bg">
    <div class="modal-box"> <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>

         <h1> Modal Title </h1>

        <p>Information about website!</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice, i am fairy new to jQuery your answer works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply reset the animation to the top each time:

```
$('.modal-box').css('top',0).stop(0,0).animate({
```

### [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/va2r1pkm/4/)

```
$('body').on('click', '.modal-button', function () {
    // show box and bg on click of button    
    var el = $('#modal-bg').fadeIn();

    $('.modal-box').css('top', 0).stop(0, 0).animate({              // <--- this line
        top: "+=300"
    }, 1000, function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

$('.modal-box .fa').on('click', function () {
    // show box and bg on click of button
    $('#modal-bg').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you just fadeOut, without removing the previously added 300px.
Add this on close:

```
$('.modal-box').animate({

        top: "-=300"
    }, 1000, function () {
        $('#modal-bg').fadeOut();

    });
```

Check this https://jsfiddle.net/va2r1pkm/1/